# Unable to apply where clause properly in python panda data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi i have following data frame

```
S.No   Description    amount
1      a, b, c        100
2      a, c           50
3      b, c           80
4      b, d           90
5      a              150
```

I want to extract only values of 'a' forexample

expected answer:

```
Description   amount
a             100
a             50
a             150
```

and sum them up as

```
Description   amount
a             300
```

But i am getting this answer:

```
Description   amount
1      a        100
2      a        50
3      nan      nan
4      nan      nan
5      a        150
```

please guide me how to properly use where clause on panda's dataframes.

Code:

```
filter = new_df ["Description"] =="a"
new_df.where(filter, inplace = True)
print (new_df)
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code you're using to get this answer?

Comment: added code above

Comment: @Qasim0787 that won't work because your `"a"` is tied up inside a string. The filter will always be false because `"a"` wouldn't ever equal any of those strings. You *could* try using `df["Description"].isin({"a",})`, but it's not a very good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.assign`, `Series.str.split`, `df.explode`, `df.query` and `Groupby.sum`:

```
In [703]: df_a = df.assign(Description=df.Description.str.split(',')).explode('Description').query('Description == "a"')

In [704]: df_a
Out[704]: 
   S.No Description  amount
0     1           a     100
1     2           a      50
4     5           a     150

In [706]: df_a.groupby('Description')['amount'].sum().reset_index()
Out[706]: 
  Description  amount
0           a     300
```

---

Or as a one-liner:

```
df.assign(letters=df['Description'].str.split(',\s'))\
  .explode('letters')\
  .query('letters == "a"')\
  .groupby('letters', as_index=False)['amount'].sum()
```

Comment: Why do all that work for one category when, presumably, OP will want to be able to do this for all the categories (they only say "a" as an example)?

Comment: @ddejohn I'm going by OP's description `I want to extract only values of 'a' `

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
In [3]: df["Description"] = df["Description"].str.split(", ")

In [4]: df.explode("Description").groupby("Description", as_index=False).sum()[["Description", "amount"]]
Out[4]:
  Description  amount
0           a     300
1           b     270
2           c     230
3           d      90
```

This allows you to get all the sums by each description, not just the `'a'` group.